# Springboot keycloak SAML Failed to resolve any signing credential

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak, spring-saml

Im working on integrating keycloak SAML with a springboot 3 application.
Its a simple rest application with one end-point.

when call the API it does not get redirected to the keycloak login, instead I get the error

```
2023-09-11T20:39:59.809+05:30  WARN 24592 --- [nio-8081-exec-9] .BasicSignatureSigningParametersResolver : Validation failure: Unable to resolve signing 
credential
2023-09-11T20:39:59.809+05:30 ERROR 24592 --- [nio-8081-exec-9] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception

org.springframework.security.saml2.Saml2Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to resolve any signing credential
at org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.web.authentication.OpenSamlSigningUtils.resolveSigningParameters(OpenSamlSigningUtils.java:116) ~[spring-security-saml2-service-provider-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.web.authentication.OpenSamlSigningUtils.sign(OpenSamlSigningUtils.java:81) ~[spring-security-saml2-service-provider-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.web.authentication.OpenSamlAuthenticationRequestResolver.resolve(OpenSamlAuthenticationRequestResolver.java:159) ~[spring-security-saml2-service-provider-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.web.authentication.OpenSaml4AuthenticationRequestResolver.resolve(OpenSaml4AuthenticationRequestResolver.java:73) ~[spring-security-saml2-service-provider-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.web.Saml2WebSsoAuthenticationRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(Saml2WebSsoAuthenticationRequestFilter.java:98) ~[spring-security-saml2-service-provider-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:117) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.web.authentication.logout.Saml2LogoutResponseFilter.doFilterInternal(Saml2LogoutResponseFilter.java:112) ~[spring-security-saml2-service-provider-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.web.authentication.logout.Saml2LogoutRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(Saml2LogoutRequestFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-saml2-service-provider-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$AroundFilterObservation$SimpleAroundFilterObservation.lambda$wrap$0(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:323) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:224) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
at org.springframework.web.filter.ServerHttpObservationFilter.doFilterInternal(ServerHttpObservationFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1740) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:an]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to resolve any signing credential
at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:204) ~[spring-core-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
at org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.web.authentication.OpenSamlSigningUtils.resolveSigningParameters(OpenSamlSigningUtils.java:112) ~[spring-security-saml2-service-provider-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
... 93 common frames omitted
```

Here is my configuration on keycloak

[![enter image description here][1]][1]
[![enter image description here][2]][2]
[![enter image description here][3]][3]

My security config class:

```
package com.manjosh.migration;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.metadata.OpenSamlMetadataResolver;
import org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.registration.RelyingPartyRegistrationRepository;
import org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.web.DefaultRelyingPartyRegistrationResolver;
import org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.web.Saml2MetadataFilter;
import org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.web.authentication.Saml2WebSsoAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

import static org.springframework.security.config.Customizer.withDefaults;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SamlSecurityConfig {
    @Autowired
    private RelyingPartyRegistrationRepository relyingPartyRegistrationRepository;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    DefaultRelyingPartyRegistrationResolver relyingPartyRegistrationResolver = new DefaultRelyingPartyRegistrationResolver(this.relyingPartyRegistrationRepository);
        Saml2MetadataFilter filter = new     Saml2MetadataFilter(relyingPartyRegistrationResolver, new OpenSamlMetadataResolver());
    http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize.anyRequest()
                    .authenticated())
            .saml2Login(withDefaults())
            .saml2Logout(withDefaults())
            .addFilterBefore(filter, Saml2WebSsoAuthenticationFilter.class);
    return http.build();
}


}

package com.manjosh.migration;


import org.opensaml.security.x509.X509Support;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.saml2.core.Saml2X509Credential;
import org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.registration.InMemoryRelyingPartyRegistrationRepository;
import org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.registration.RelyingPartyRegistration;
import org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.registration.RelyingPartyRegistrationRepository;
import org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.registration.RelyingPartyRegistrations;

import java.io.File;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

@Configuration
public class Config {
    @Bean
    protected RelyingPartyRegistrationRepository relyingPartyRegistrations() {
    RelyingPartyRegistration registration = null;
    ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
    try {
        File verificationKey = new File(classLoader.getResource("saml-certificate/keycloak.crt").getFile());
        X509Certificate certificate = X509Support.decodeCertificate(verificationKey);
        Saml2X509Credential credential = Saml2X509Credential.verification(certificate);
        registration = RelyingPartyRegistrations
                .fromMetadataLocation("http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/migration/protocol/saml/descriptor")
                .registrationId("keycloak")
                .assertingPartyDetails(party -> party.entityId("springboot-app")
                        .verificationX509Credentials(c -> c.add(credential)))
                .build();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return new InMemoryRelyingPartyRegistrationRepository(registration);
}
}
```

for certificate I used the certificate present in the SAML metadata URL. I just enclosed it with
`-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` and `-----END CERTIFICATE-----`

here is my metadata XML

```
<md:EntityDescriptor xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" 
xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" entityID="http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/migration">
<md:IDPSSODescriptor WantAuthnRequestsSigned="true" protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
<md:KeyDescriptor use="signing">
<ds:KeyInfo>
<ds:KeyName>Ve1ljPni2EOqoZUc9kqAi1pbp1V7-gORtFMhZd2623o</ds:KeyName>
<ds:X509Data>
    <ds:X509Certificate>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</ds:X509Certificate>
</ds:X509Data>
</ds:KeyInfo>
</md:KeyDescriptor>
<md:ArtifactResolutionService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP" Location="http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/migration/protocol/saml/resolve" index="0"/>
<md:SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/migration/protocol/saml"/>
<md:SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location="http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/migration/protocol/saml"/>
<md:SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Artifact" Location="http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/migration/protocol/saml"/>
<md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent</md:NameIDFormat>
<md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient</md:NameIDFormat>
<md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified</md:NameIDFormat>
<md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress</md:NameIDFormat>
<md:SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/migration/protocol/saml"/>
<md:SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location="http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/migration/protocol/saml"/>
<md:SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP" Location="http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/migration/protocol/saml"/>
<md:SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Artifact" Location="http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/migration/protocol/saml"/>
</md:IDPSSODescriptor>
</md:EntityDescriptor>
```

Please help.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVbLY.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUJkw.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTUFt.png